# Raid 10 gone - how to rebuild / find informations

Tags: raid, arch-linux, software-raid, mdadm, raid-10

Because of another task, i had to disconnect all the raid hdd's from my pc.
Shutdown -> disconnect hdd's -> boot -> shutdown -> connect hdd's -> boot -> *raid completely lost*.

`mdadm --assemble --scan` returns:
`mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically`

The hdd's used for the raid 10 are available and fully functionally, but i have no clue how i exactly configured the hdd's for the raid 10 (setup was some years ago..).

Is there any possible way to find some information's about the exact setup of the lost raid?
Or any way to recreate the array without loss of data, if the array setup for the recreate is wrong?

Does somebody may have any clue, why my array was lost after the disconnect/connect of the disks?

Comment: Did you reinstall them in the same exact order?

Comment: @Ramhound No, i do not know the exact order. The setup ist some years ago and i didn't documented the setup... Is there a way to determinate the correct order now?